# Geotagging a captured video

Tags: android

Any one have idea about how to geotag the capture video?
 I have check it for images http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

but can not find much about the video.
 I have also check android app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dailyroads.v&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the class used to store meta data about the video: [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

As you can see that Android does not support Geotagging for videos.

So in summary:

- `3gp` and `mp4` containers can't hold GeoTagging information
- `mov` files can.
- Android does not support geotagging for videos. The video's geo position is stored, but in the Android's internal database.

Comment: Actually, it does indirectly. You add the information to the media database, rather than to the file itself. There are columns for both latitude and longitude. Here is an example of how to add data to videos: http://www.androidcookbook.info/android-media/adding-video-metadata.html

Comment: @Reno any updates on this answer? Does android still not support geotagging each frame of a video?