# Can I somehow embed location data into a video file in android?

Tags: android, video, gps, ffmpeg, location

Can I somehow embed location data into a video file in android?

Currently my app creates a video file and gets location info but I have no idea if it is possible to embed location info (lattitude, longitude) into my video file.

I could use ffmpeg or whatever for that (I'm using ffmpeg for some operations on my video).

Alas, I have not a slightest idea how to embed GPS data into my video, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be a duplicate of this one: [Geotagging a captured video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310317/geotagging-a-captured-video)

But nevertheless, taken from: http://mobile.dzone.com/news/reading-gps-latitude-and

> You may know that even Android doesn’t “geotag” videos this is not quite true. Because after using you gallery you can see where those videos are shot. This is fantastic, but actually the real information about where the video has been taken is not into the video file, but it’s in an additional log file that keeps it. Thus actually the video files doesn’t know the geo coordinates.

So I think you can't. You have to store the geo information in an extra file, like Android is doing it. Because MP4 cannot store geotags.

But .MOV files can. So if you can store a MOV file, maybe you can add geotags to it.